# How to avoid using sendBlocking in kotlin channel producer?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I'm using a kotlin channel in order to migrate a database: I have 1 producer and multiple processors which write to database. The producer just sends the batches of documents to channel:

```
fun CoroutineScope.produceDocumentBatches(mongoCollection: MongoCollection<Document>) = produce<List<Document>> {
    var batch = arrayListOf<Document>()
    for ((counter, document) in mongoCollection.find().withIndex()) {
        if ((counter + 1) % 100 == 0) {
            sendBlocking(batch)
            batch = arrayListOf()
        }
        batch.add(document)
    }
    if (batch.isNotEmpty()) sendBlocking(batch) }
}
```

This is how my processors look like:

```
private fun CoroutineScope.processDocumentsAsync(
        documentDbCollection: MongoCollection<Document>,
        channel: ReceiveChannel<List<Document>>,
        numberOfProcessedDocuments: AtomicInteger
) = launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
    // do processing
}
```

And this is how I use them in the script:

```
fun run() = runBlocking {
        val producer = produceDocumentBatches(mongoCollection)
        (1..64).map { processDocumentsAsync(documentDbCollection, producer, count) }
}
```

So is it fine to use `sendBlocking` with regards to performance? If I use just `send` I create many suspending functions inside one coroutine because writes to database are much slower than reads and I get `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space`. Do I understand correctly that producer blocks `Main` thread but it's fine for performance because all consumers are executed on IO threads?

Comment: It's not the `send` that causes your OutOfMemory problem. It is something else. You should not be needing `sendBlocking` in this code. No reason for it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe my understanding is not correct, but I think you are not creating many suspending functions inside a coroutine, not sure if it even makes sense to say something like that. As you haven't defined a capacity when using `produce` function, default value is zero and it is using a [RendezvousChannel](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.channels/-channel/index.html). It is going to suspend till another coroutine invokes `receive`. I don't think you need `sendBlocking`.

My guess is that you are using two many consumers and has two many `Document` instances in memory, it could be the reason for the `OutOfMemoryError`. What is the size of each `Document`? What are your jvm heap configurations?

My suggestions:

1. Use `send` instead of `sendBlocking`
2. Decrease the number of consumers to a much smaller number and see if the `OutOfMemory` persists.
3. Use `clear()` to erase the `ArrayList` instead of creating a new instance.

If it works fine after those suggestions, try to increase the number of consumers and check if everything still works fine.